# h:inputTex with f:ajax listener not fired in p:datatable and p:columns

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this **p:dataTable**

```
<h:form id="forms" styleClass="tTablas" prependId="false">
<p:dataTable var="row" id="list" value="#{BB.dataTable}" rowIndexVar="i">
    <p:column headerText="id">
        <h:outputText value="#{row.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:columns var="fecha" value="#{BB.lFechaEntradaVigor}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{fecha}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.getCoste(fecha)}" styleClass="#{row.isValido(fecha)?'vigor':''}" rendered="#{!row.isUpdatable(fecha)}">
            <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2" />
        </h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{BB.valor}" rendered="#{row.isUpdatable(fecha)}">
            <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2" />
            <f:ajax render="@this" listener="#{grupoValoracionSiaBB.changeValor(fecha, row, i)}" />
        </h:inputText>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

`</h:form>`

I did `dataTable` in this way because `p:columns` do not accept `p:cellEditor` and I need to know what column is updated, then I have created method `changeValor(Date fecha, Object enitidad, Integer fila)` and I call in `f:ajax` `listener` but do not fired.
Any Idea???
THX

Comment: Do you want to have the listener fired with any change, or when the whole `h:form` is submitted? If you want to have it updated by any change, add `event="change"` to the `f:ajax`

Comment: I added event but does not work

Comment: You also have a `h:form` around the datatable, I suppose...

Comment: Yes I have `h:form` around the dataTable

Comment: My problem was I worked with **Primefaces 3.5**, I change version to 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use p:inputText and p:ajax and in p:ajax tag add process="@this" and event.

Comment: I change my **h:inputText** to `<p:inputText value="#{grupoValoracionSiaBB.valor}" rendered="#{row.isUpdatable(fecha)}">
     <p:ajax event="change" update="@this" process="@this" listener="#{grupoValoracionSiaBB.changeValor(fecha, row, i)}" />
    </p:inputText>` but does not work

Comment: But if **p:inputText** are out of dataTable works!!!! can use **js** and call a **function** but I do not think is best solution. Any idea???